# System can not find the path specified

Tags: java, file, ioexception

I am trying to create a new file using the `createNewFile()` method in Java:

```
File savegame = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + File.separator + "Game" + File.separator + "test" + ".ser");

try
{
    savegame.createNewFile();
} 
catch(IOException exc)
{
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get an IOException which says that the system can not find the path specified and can not understand why?

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of the path in savegame? The error message is pretty clear. The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Also, check that `System.getenv("APPDATA")` returns an existing directory pathname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the directory in which the file should be created exists. To create the directory before creating the file, you can do the following:

```
File savegame = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + File.separator + "Game" + File.separator + "test" + ".ser");

try
{
    savegame.getParentFile().mkdirs();  // create parent directory
    savegame.createNewFile();
} 
catch(IOException exc)
{
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

From the documentation of `File#mkdirs()`:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that I have to create the parent directories first.